# How to take a function as an input

Tags: discussion

I want to make a challenge about genetic algorithm. It is not sandboxed right now. But the task is given a list of neuclide(String with only "ATGC"), the scoring function, and another parameter, you must do a genetic algorithm. (Be note it is the sketch of the sketch) However, the scoring function is inputted as function. How to do that?

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be no existing consensus for this, and very few challenges require functions as input, so you can pretty much decide it for yourself. I would allow the two methods in [Peter Taylor's answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8300/32014), and a third alternative:

- If a language can pass functions as function arguments by some standard mechanism, like first-class functions, function pointers or CJam blocks, then the scoring function can simply be taken as an argument.
- If a language has `eval` or equivalent, which interprets and runs a string as code, then a string that defines the scoring function can be taken as input.
- One can also assume that the scoring function has already been defined as `S` (or some other name), and can be used in the answer. The definition of `S` is not counted toward the score.

If you want, you can restrict the last alternative to languages that don't support the first two.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of your third option, but I agree with it.

Answer (score 6):

However works.

If an answer is in a language which allows passing functions (as first class objects, function pointers, etc) then the answer can be given as a function which takes another function as one of its parameters.

If an answer is in a language which has some form of eval then it can be a function or a full program which takes a string and evals it appropriately.

If a language doesn't have any suitable mechanism, tough luck.

Comment: Or Java 8's "functional interfaces" can also be used

Comment: If you *really* want to be inclusive you could allow people to designate a position in the source code where the "function" can be dumped into (as a plain code snippet). That's probably unnecessary though.